# Visual Studio 2005 solution file issue

Tags: visual-studio-2005, scons

Hello
I'm using scons to generate Visual Studio 2005 project files ( sln, vcproj ). When I open it right after generation everything is ok. The problem starts when I try to open sln file for the second time. Visual Studio 2005 is telling me that project need to be converted to 2005 format because somehow it is recognized as 2003 .NET. I discovered that after I close Visual Studio for the first time it saves *.user file right next to vcproj file. When I deleted  *.user file and tried to open sln file once again everything worked ok.

My question is how to force VS 2005 not to generate *.user files. What are those files ?
In the past I was using scons to build VS 2003 .NET sln files and everything was ok.
Why it is being generated ?

Best Regards
Lukasz

Comment: Is there a problem with allowing the project to be converted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is after conversion I got error that project can not be converted and there were errors found during conversion. The weirdest thing for me is how the project can be treated as 2005 project for the first time but not for the second time I open the sln file. There must be some extra stuff written somewhere that messes with the sln or vcproj file.